# SQL Query with a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I need to retrieve the player number, name, street and town for all players that live in the same street and town as the players with number 6 or 7;

I am not sure how to write the SQL Query, i think i need to have a subquery in the WHERE clause but can't figure out how to do it.

This is what i came up with, but i have no way of testing it at this point

```
SELECT playerNo, name, street, town
FROM Players
WHERE street IN ( SELECT street, playerNo
                  FROM Players
                  WHERE playerNo IN (6,7));
AND town IN (SELECT town, playerNo
             FROM Players
             WHERE playerNo IN (6,7));
```

Should be compatible with Oracle 10g

Thanks to everyone who replied!

Comment: You can test your query at SQL Fiddle, so next time you won't have "no way of testing it." You'll see, for example, that it doesn't run: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5ad1/1, but that one of the answers below does. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5ad1/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't state your DBMS so this is the ANSI SQL solution (which works in Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, Teradata, MySQL and probably a lot of others as well):

```
SELECT playerNo, name, street, town
FROM Players
WHERE (street, town) IN (SELECT street, town
                         FROM Players
                         WHERE playerNo IN (6,7));
```

A side note regarding the `IN` operator:

your the expression `town IN (SELECT town, playerNO ...` is invalid because the subselect must the exact same number of columns as the left hand side of the `IN` operator. In your case you would have to write `town IN (SELECT town FROM ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
select t.playerNumber, t.name, t.street, t.town
from tablename t
inner join (select street, town from tablename where playerNumber in (6,7)) aux on aux.street = t.street and aux.town = t.town
```

Comment: this looks *really* weird to me. Why do you put `where` inside `join` ? O_o

Comment: The "inner" select gets the street and town of the players 6 and 7. The "outer" select gets the info that have the street and town given in the "inner" select. It does the trick, but like you said it's possible in a simpler way :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p1.playerNo, p1.name, p1.street, p1.town
FROM Players AS p1
INNER JOIN Players AS p2 ON p2.street = p1.street AND p2.town = p1.town
WHERE p2.playerNo IN (6,7)
```

It's often best to avoid subqueries because the database optimizer can't 'see inside the parens'.

Comment: That's a nice solution as well (although I'm not entirely convinced that Oracle "*can't see inside the parens*").

Comment: Thanks. Oracle probably is smarter than a lot of other DBs. I know I have often sped things up on other systems by refactoring a subquery. Most of the time it's more important that the thing is readable in a month.